Toolbar icons, project arrows too small
enter image description hereI'm using the latest version of STS 4.22.1, but regardless of the installed version, the icons appear small and blurry as shown in the image. I didn't have this issue on my old computer.
I tried some configurations in the SpringToolSuite4.ini file
